# Search GitHub source files via Google Search

Tags: google-search, github

I'm trying to search via Google to find a particular Ruby source file responsible for an issue and the OpenSSL function of interest is `SSL_get_peer_certificate`. If I find the function I'll probably find the relevant Ruby code.

However, searching Ruby source files is *not* returning expected results. I'm searching with the following, and it returned zero results.

> SSL_get_peer_certificate site:github.com/ruby/ruby

This returned a page or two of results, which is almost certainly wrong (it should have produced a cornucopia):

```
ssl site:github.com/ruby/ruby
```

How does one search GitHub projects?

(This is related to a question on Stack Overflow, [Verifying only that a SSL certificate is signed by a CA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283037/verifying-only-that-a-ssl-certificate-is-signed-by-a-ca) where I believe the problem is Ruby is performing host name matching only based on the `CN`, and not the `SAN`.)

Comment: Ah, OK thanks. According to @Benjamin, the robots.txt` allows Google to index it, so Google should be crawling the project. Whether Google indexes it is a different story (apparently not - *q.v.*).

Comment: select-menu-item js-navigation-item links on the github pages have rel="nofollow" which will most likely stop Google spidering any further than the project main pages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `site:` and `inurl:` in order to narrow your results as desired.

In your example it would be:

> SSL_get_peer_certificate site:github.com inurl:ruby

This will search for "SSL_get_peer_certificate" on the github.com domain, and only if "ruby" is part of the URL, as it would be in **github.com/ruby/ruby**

But you can also use GitHub.com itself for code searches across all repos, or just [down to a single repository](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=SSL_get_peer_certificate).

In this case it would bring up **[ruby/ext/openssl/ossl_ssl.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ee5edc5950dcd6d9577b35935e8028b25c0415c5/ext/openssl/ossl_ssl.c#L1631)** as containing the reference you're looking for.